# Add and get average of two columns for the same record SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a table in SQL Server which look like this

```
imdb_title_id | allgenders_0age_avg_vote | allgenders_18age_avg_vote
---------------------------------------------------------------------
tt0000574       6                         6.2
tt0001892       null                      null
```

What I want to get is

```
imdb_title_id | yearsRating
-------------------------
tt0000574       6.1
tt0001892       null
```

I tried

```
SELECT IMDB_Movies.imdb_title_id,
(SELECT Avg(IMDB_Ratings.allgenders_0age_avg_vote + IMDB_Ratings.allgenders_18age_avg_vote)
From IMDB_Movies INNER JOIN IMDB_Ratings
on IMDB_Movies.imdb_title_id = IMDB_Ratings.imdb_title_id
and IMDB_Ratings.allgenders_0age_avg_vote != null and IMDB_Ratings.allgenders_18age_avg_vote != null
group by IMDB_Movies.imdb_title_id) AS yearsRating
From IMDB_Movies, IMDB_Actors, IMDB_Ratings, Actors_Movies
```

but it gives me null in all yearsRating values so what query should I execute

Comment: Shouldn't this be a simple expression-based column selection? Why do you think this requires grouping or sub-query? Something like `SELECT imdb_title_id, (allgenders_0age_avg_vote + allgenders_18age_avg_vote)/2 FROM...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules for computation are not clearly defined.

If you want the computation for each row:

```
select 
    imdb_title_id,
    (allgenders_0age_avg_vote + allgenders_18age_avg_vote) / 2 years_rating
from mytable
```

But then if *any* of the two values is `null`, so will be the result. If you want to consider `null` as `0`s:

```
select 
    imdb_title_id,
    (coalesce(allgenders_0age_avg_vote, 0) + coalesce(allgenders_18age_avg_vote, 0)) / 2 years_rating
from mytable
```

If you have more than one row with the same `imdb_title_id` and you want the result across rows:

```
select 
    imdb_title_id,
    avg(allgenders_0age_avg_vote + allgenders_18age_avg_vote) / 2 years_rating
from mytable
group by imdb_title_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This does that calculation with the data you have shown:

```
select imdb_title_id, 
       (allgenders_0age_avg_vote + allgenders_18age_avg_vote) / 2 as yearsRating
from IMDB_Ratings
```

If this is not what you want, then you should provide more details.

Comment: Take care of operator precedence.